# Why are the results of integer division and converting to an int after division different for large numbers?

Tags: python, floating-point, division

```
print(10**40//2)
print(int(10**40/2))
```

Output of the codes:

```
5000000000000000000000000000000000000000
5000000000000000151893014213501833445376
```

Why different values? Why the output of the second `print()` looks so?

Comment: Take a look at `10**40/2` directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The floating point representation of `10**40//2` is not accurate:

```
>>> format(float(10**40//2), '.0f')
'5000000000000000151893014213501833445376'
```

That's because floating point arithmetic is only ever an approximation, especially when you go beyond what your CPU can accurately model (as floating point is handled in hardware).

The integer division never has to represent the `10**40` number as a float, it only has to divide the integer, which in Python can be arbitrarily large without precision loss.

Also see:

- [*Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in the Python tutorial
- [*What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://floating-point-gui.de/)
- [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Also look at the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) if you must use higher-precision floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `10**40` never gets represented as a float in either case: true division of two integers doesn't convert both arguments to floats and *then* divide: instead, it does a single correctly-rounded division, as though computing the quotient to infinite precision and then rounding it to fit the float format.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: right; adjusted the example to turn the int into a float to make that clearer.