# How to manage division of huge numbers in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, division

I have a 100 digit number and I am trying to put all the digits of the number into a list, so that I can perform operations on them. To do this, I am using the following code:

```
for x in range (0, 1000):
   list[x] = number % 10
   number = number / 10
```

But the problem I am facing is that I am getting an overflow error something like too large number float/integer. I even tried using following alternative

```
number = int (number / 10)
```

How can I divide this huge number with the result back in integer type, that is no floats?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In Python 3, `number / 10` will try to return a `float`. However, floating point values can't be of arbitrarily large size in Python and if `number` is large an `OverflowError` will be raised.

You can find the maximum that Python floating point values can take on your system using the `sys` module:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

To get around this limitation, instead use `//` to get an integer back from the division of the two integers:

```
number // 10
```

This will return the `int` floor value of `number / 10` (it does not produce a float). Unlike floats, `int` values can be as large as you need them to be in Python 3 (within memory limits).

You can now divide the large numbers. For instance, in Python 3:

```
>>> 2**3000 / 10
OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float

>>> 2**3000 // 10
123023192216111717693155881327...
```

Comment: But does this works on long int also? I suppose in case of a large number, python will automatically choose it as long it?

Comment: In Python 3 there is no `long` type (integers can be any size). It works in Python 2 with both types.

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know about // division before.

Comment: Careful.  Just because you don't get an `OverflowError` doesn't mean the division is correct.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740938/why-are-the-results-of-integer-division-and-converting-to-an-int-after-division

Comment: @Maxpm: that's true for true division (`/`) where you get back a float, but for integer `a` and `b` you can be sure that the integer division `a // b` is correct, regardless of the magnitude of the resulting integer.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an integer and you want each digit in a list, you can use:

```
>>> map(int,list(str(number)))
[1, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 6, 4, 2, 2, 6, 8, 3, 9, 7, 5, 0, 3, 6, 6, 4, 0, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 2, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 8, 4, 0, 6, 6, 4, 5, 0, 9, 2, 4, 8, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 9, 9, 9, 7, 0, 1, 7, 4, 8, 2, 4, 4, 2, 9, 6, 9, 5, 1, 7, 1, 3, 4, 8, 5, 1, 3, 3, 1, 7, 9, 0, 1, 0, 1, 9, 3, 8, 4, 2, 0, 1, 9, 2, 9]
```

it transform the int into a string, then `list` will take each character of the string and put it in a list. Finally, `map` will convert each item of the list into an int again

Answer (score 2):

Python will automatically handle large `int`s of arbitrary length. What it won't do is handle `float`s of arbitrary length so you need to make sure you're not getting floats along the way.

Comment: true. But, how can I avoid that in case I am dividing the number. Is there any function to handle this.

Comment: yeah as previously mentioned, using the // operator will help you ensure your answer is always an int.

Answer (score 1):

Try `int(number) % 10`. You can only mod integers.

Comment: The number is already integer and it works. Problem happens in case of division. When I try to divide it by 10, i just want remaining integer. If i use int(number/10) i get error number too big for float.

Comment: That's interesting because `x mod 10` should be in the subset [0, 9]; thus, division by 10 would be 0 by integer division.

Comment: Oh wait, python's `/` isn't integer division. `//` is the way to go.