# long integers division error in python while finding least common multiple

Tags: python, python-3.x, lcm

Normally, program doesn't throw an error for small  however when it comes to these numbers it returns wrong division result

```
def leastCommonMultiple(n1, n2):
    a=n1
    b=n2
    while n2!=0:
        (n1, n2) = (n2, n1 % n2)
   print (n1) # greatest common divisior for given input is 5
   print(a*b) # for given numbers 231871064940156750
   return int((a*b)/n1) #wrong result    46374212988031352



numStr=input()
nums=numStr.split()
num1=int(nums[0])
num2=int(nums[1])
lcm=leastCommonMultiple(num1, num2)
print (lcm)


Input:
226553150 1023473145

Your output:
46374212988031352

Correct output:
46374212988031350
```

WHAT I WROTE EXPLANATION:

```
leastCommonMultiple = (Num1*Num2)/greatestCommonDivisor
```

So in while loop I found `greatestCommonDivisor` by using euclidean method

and I used the formula `(LCM = n1*n2/ GCD )`

I hope I explained the problem clearly. What can I solve this problem can you help me please?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946595/how-to-manage-division-of-huge-numbers-in-python

Comment: thanks, it taught me extra information. Luckily I just found out the problem. I will try to do better searches for my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use // in python 3 for integer division. I just found out this