# How to do correct division for large numbers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, division

Why is there an error for division in both: int and float? and how to correct it?

```
print(int(231871064940156750/5),231871064940156750/5%100)

# output: 46374212988031352 52.0

# correct number: 46374212988031350
```

Comment: What do you mean "both int and float"? You didn't divide any floats.

Comment: Aran-Fey, at first I thought that the problem was only because of converting from float to int, but as shown also float number is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a very nice explantion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946595/how-to-manage-division-of-huge-numbers-in-python)

What you need is

```py
print(int(231871064940156750//5),231871064940156750/5%100)
```

The use of // rather than / for integer division is for compatibility with Python 3.x for no extra effort.

[Also make sure to take a quick look](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

for the / and // operators

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two questions here. I'll address the first part of your print statement, which is `print(int(231871064940156750/5))`: see this related post [long integers division error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946595/how-to-manage-division-of-huge-numbers-in-python)...

I tried the suggestion therein (using two slashes) and it arrived at the quotient you expected.

```
>>> print(int(231871064940156750//5))
46374212988031350
>>>
```

[Informit.com](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=674692&seqNum=4) explains, "...Python has two division operators, a single slash character for classic division and a double-slash for “floor” division (rounds down to nearest whole number). Classic division means that if the operands are both integers, it will perform floor division, while for floating point numbers, it represents true division."