# Python: Why is the number changing from int in a float type?

Tags: python, int

As I know, python can work with arbitrarily large numbers, from the int type. But as soon as n > 512, I get an error. 
Thanks in advance

```
n = int(512)
num = int((4 ** n) / 4)

print(int(num))
```

like I sad, this works. But when n > 512 I get this, when I run the program, why?:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_", line 10, in <module>
    num = int((4 ** n) / 4)
OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Use floor divide `//` instead of `/`.

Comment: I'm actually unable to reproduce this on either Python 2.7.15 or 3.7.2.

Comment: @AKX I can reproduce it in Python 3.7. As OP remarks, the error only occurs for n *>* 512. And it won't happen in Python 2.7 without `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry, I blindly copied the example. Off-by-one error :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage division of huge numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946595/how-to-manage-division-of-huge-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using the floating division operator, use the integer one instead `//`:

```
>>> num = int((4 ** 512) // 4)
>>> num
44942328371557897693232629769725618340449424473557664318357520289433168951375240783177119330601884005280028469967848339414697442203604155623211857659868531094441973356216371319075554900311523529863270738021251442209537670585615720368478277635206809290837627671146574559986811484619929076208839082406056034304
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, now its working. But can I then not just write: num = ((a ** 512) // 4)  ?

Comment: @Mister_X ofc, you can use whatever.