# Python integer division when integers are very long

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, long-integer, integer-division

I have an integer N with 148 digits:

```
N = 189880498154874410908471072304455370977803974052993577744714297943955583553239505756289235529074177090189772883747055299991539896681082073700
```

If i do the following:

```
int(N/5)
```

I get

```
37976099630974880812875385175875453232636859166769727967703624184530129537145373074783104855861950095228086215792238563575229919019266998272
```

which is absolutely wrong!!

Instead, if i use arbitrary floating point precision with mpmath, I get the correct result

```
from mpmath import mp, mpf as f
mp.dps = 200; mp.pretty = True

f(N)/5
>> 37976099630974882181694214460891074195560794810598715548942859588791116710647901151257847105814835418037954576749411059998307979336216414740.0
```

So, why is the first result wrong? I believed that Python could handle with integers of arbitrary size

Comment: please have a look at this question : [The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946595/how-to-manage-division-of-huge-numbers-in-python)

Comment: `int(N/5)` turns the floating-point result back into an integer; it does not prevent `/` from producing a floating-point value (with all the attendant imprecision that implies) in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python 3:

// is used for integer division, this will give you the correct result.

```
print(N//5)
```

output:

```
37976099630974882181694214460891074195560794810598715548942859588791116710647901151257847105814835418037954576749411059998307979336216414740
```

where
/ is used for floating point division, so it might give errors while rounding up the digits.