# why is my int() conversion looking so weird?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to take a number and divide it by 100 to get 1%, but when i tried to convert it to integer using the int(), it's giving me some weird output. i have no clue what i'm doing wrong here.

```
totalsupply = 1000000000000000000000000000000
onepercent = int((totalsupply/100))

print(totalsupply)
print(onepercent)
```

the output is coming out as such:

```
1000000000000000000000000000000
9999999999999999583119736832
[Finished in 68ms]
```

I was expecting the onepercent to be this: 10000000000000000000000000000.

Comment: When you conduct a division, Python converts the result to the nearest approximate binary fraction. This means some of the information gets lost in translation. See the documentation on floats. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946595/how-to-manage-division-of-huge-numbers-in-python), python tries to convert the number to a float on a division. However, floats are limited to `1.7976931348623157e+308`. A workaround is to use the `//` operator which returns an int from the division, so for your example:

```
totalsupply = 1000000000000000000000000000000
onepercent = totalsupply//100

print(totalsupply)
print(onepercent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a [built-in integer type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) that has infinite precision. That's what you are creating with your first line

```
 totalsupply = 1000000000000000000000000000000
```

However, python has two [division operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations). The standard division "slash" operator ("/") is floating-point operation, whereas the double-slash gives integers.

Hence `totalsupply/100` is a floating point number, which has finite precision, and so the closest it can do is `9999999999999999583119736832`.

However, if instead you do

```
onepercent = totalsupply//100
print(onepercent)
```

you get the expected `100000000000000000000000000000`.