# Remove Last Number of a Integer

Tags: python

I have searched for a few answers and none of them seems to work.

Below is an example but the code does not work and gives errors. I am using Python 2.7.

```
operationTwo = 91239
operationTwo = operationTwo[:-1]
print(operationTwo)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code you found which is `slicing`, works but not on `integers`. If you want to use it you can convert the number to `str` for slicing then convert it back to `int`. It is not the best practice but it can be done as the following:

```
operationTwo = 91239
operationTwo = int(str(operationTwo)[:-1])
print(operationTwo)
```

I would however go with `integer` division, like:

```
operationTwo = 91239
operationTwo = operationTwo // 10
print(operationTwo)
```

Comment: Both of these methods, as written, will fail, if the integer is a single digit. In the string slice don't attempt to int() it. In both cases it's best to test for a single digit because the correct answer would be space(None) and not zero.

Answer (score 8):

That is very simple:

```
operationTwo = int(operationTwo / 10)
```

Comment: or `operationTwo // 10`

Comment: This will fail with single-digit numbers, because it will always return `0` instead of an empty value.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes but it depends on what he wants to do.

Comment: @ekhumoro python 2.7: 1 / 10 = 0, 1 // 10 = 0 python3: 1 / 10 = 0.1, 1 // 10 = 0, Looks like sticking with `str` slicing is the way to go

Comment: @RolfofSaxony. Yes, but this answer is using `int(1 / 10)`, which works okay for python3. The issue is how to interpret "remove the last digit", if there's only one digit.

Comment: @ekhumoro It is probably semantics, as you suggest but both int(1/10) and int(1//10) return 0 (zero) which is incorrect

Comment: I am new to Python. Could someone please explain why I am getting incorrect answers when I do num/10 where num is a very large number (30 digits, and by incorrect I mean when num= 10^29 the answer is not 10^28), but num//10 works perfectly.

Comment: @vivekagarwal277 I believe this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740938/why-are-the-results-of-integer-division-and-converting-to-an-int-after-division

Answer (score 1):

```html
operationTwo = 91239
operationTwo = operationTwo %10
#now operationTwo = 9123
operationTwo = operationTwo //10
digit2 = operationTwo %10
#now operationTwo = 912
operationTwo = operationTwo //10
digit3 = operationTwo %10
#now operationTwo = 91
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).