# math.floor() and // produce different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

In Python3.4 I would expect operations `math.floor()` and `//` to produce the same result. They don't.

```
import math

n=20844627638611523
print (math.floor(n/2))
print (n//2)
```

prints:

```
10422313819305762
10422313819305761
```

why?

Comment: This is essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/26740938/270986 (except with `math.floor` in place of `int`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your expression n/2.  This returns a float `1.0422313819305762e+16` -- you lost a bit of precision inside that last digit.  With that loss, your subsequent `floor` operation returns an unexpected result.